# Wrong encoding of email attachment

Tags: python, windows, email, encoding

I have a python 2.7 script running on windows. It logs in gmail, checks for new e-mails and attachments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

file_types = ["pdf", "doc", "docx"] # download attachments with these extentions

login = "login"
passw = "password"

imap_server = "imap.gmail.com"
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 587

from smtplib import SMTP
from email.parser import HeaderParser
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import datetime
import os
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        while True:
            session = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
            try:
                rv, data = session.login(login, passw)
                print "Logged in: ", rv
            except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
                print "Login failed!"
                sys.exit(1)

            rv, mailboxes = session.list()
            rv, data = session.select(foldr)
            rv, data = session.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
            for num in data[ 0 ].split():
                rv, data = session.fetch(num, "(RFC822)")
                for rpart in data:
                    if isinstance(rpart, tuple):
                        msg = email.message_from_string(rpart[ 1 ])
                        to = email.utils.parseaddr(msg[ "From" ])[ 1 ]
                text = data[ 0 ][ 1 ]
                msg = email.message_from_string(text)
                got = []
                for part in msg.walk():
                    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                        continue
                    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                        continue
                    filename = part.get_filename()
                    print "file: ", filename
                    print "Extention: ", filename.split(".")[ -1 ]
                    if filename.split(".")[ -1 ] not in file_types:
                        continue
                    data = part.get_payload(decode = True)
                    if not data:
                        continue
                    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    if not os.path.isdir("CONTENT"):
                        os.mkdir("CONTENT")
                    if not os.path.isdir("CONTENT/" + date):
                        os.mkdir("CONTENT/" + date)
                    ftime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S")
                    new_file = "CONTENT/" + date + "/" + ftime + "_" + filename
                    f = open(new_file, 'wb')
                    print "Got new file %s from %s" % (new_file, to)
                    got.append(filename.encode("utf-8"))
                    f.write(data)
                    f.close()
            session.close()
            session.logout()
            time.sleep(60)
    except:
        print "TARFUN!"
```

And the problem is that the last print reads garbage:
`=?UTF-8?B?0YfQsNGB0YLRjCAxINGC0LXQutGB0YIg0LzQtdGC0L7QtNC40YfQutC4LmRv?=`
for example
so later checks don't work. On linux it works just fine.
For now I tryed to d/e[n]code filename to utf-8. But it did nothing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with enough code to run something (and extraneous code, like the IMAP fetching, removed), and input data to run it on (e.g., maybe as a string literal in the source)?

Comment: No, that's not a minimal, complete example. Nobody can run that code or test anything (unless you give us your gmail username and password and promise to never receive any more mail or otherwise change anything about your mailbox, which isn't reasonable). Please, look at the help link I gave, and do what I suggested: remove the extraneous code, and give us the input data for the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the spec that defines the filename field, [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183), section 2.3, it says:

> Current [[RFC 2045]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) grammar restricts parameter values (and hence
> Content-Disposition filenames) to US-ASCII.  We recognize the great
> desirability of allowing arbitrary character sets in filenames, but
> it is beyond the scope of this document to define the necessary
> mechanisms.  We expect that the basic [[RFC 1521]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521) 'value'
> specification will someday be amended to allow use of non-US-ASCII
> characters, at which time the same mechanism should be used in the
> Content-Disposition filename parameter.

There are proposed RFCs to handle this. In particular, it's been suggested that filenames be handled as `encoded-word`s, as defined by [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987), [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), and [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231). In brief this means either RFC 2047 format:

```
"=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

… or RFC 2231 format:

```
"=?" charset ["*" language] "?" encoded-text "?="
```

Some mail agents are already using this functionality, others don't know what to do with it. The `email` package in Python 2.x is among those that don't know what to do with it. (It's possible that the later version in Python 3.x does, or that it may change in the future, but that won't help you if you want to stick with 2.x.) So, if you want to parse this, you have to do it yourself.

In your example, you've got a filename in RFC 2047 format, with charset `UTF-8` (which is usable directly as a Python encoding name), encoding `B`, which means Base-64, and content `0YfQsNGB0YLRjCAxINGC0LXQutGB0YIg0LzQtdGC0L7QtNC40YfQutC4LmRv`. So, you have to base-64 decode that, then UTF-8-decode that, and you get `u'часть 1 текст методички.do'`.

If you want to do this more generally, you're going to have to write code which tries to interpret each filename in RFC 2231 format if possible, in RFC 2047 format otherwise, and does the appropriate decoding steps. This code isn't trivial enough to write in a StackOverflow answer, but the basic idea is pretty simple, as demonstrated above, so you should be able to write it yourself. You may also want to search PyPI for existing implementations.

Comment: That trick with b64 decoding and then utf-8 decoding worked! But the string misses last character: that's .doc document. How so? 0.0

Comment: Your characterization of RFC2231 is incorrect; it does not have the `=?` prefix and `?=` suffix of RFC2047 but rather a format like `Content-Type: application/x-stuff; name*0*=us-ascii'en'This%20is%20even%20more%20;
name*1*=%2A%2A%2Afun%2A%2A%2A%20; name*2="isn't it!"` (adapted from one of the complex examples in the RFC). What you describe is an extension of the basic RFC2047 format which is indeed defined in RFC2231 but the main header format for defining filenames etc is quite different.

Comment: Also, RFC5987 applies to HTTP, not email.