# Python 3.x GMAIL Attachment Filename

Tags: python-3.x, filenames, email-attachments, gmail-imap, os.path

I've looked at lots of example code to download attachments to my local machine but none are working and I am stuck.

I can get subject lines of mail, set delete flags etc, but not save attachments

All good except for this bit.  Here is my code to get the attachment of the email and write it locally:

```
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(detach_dir, 'attachments', fileName)
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                print (fileName)
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

This is my problem, I think.  The filename I see is not good for a Windows filename.  I checked in debug, what the filename is:

```
   print (part.get_filename())
   =?utf-8?Q?180=20Score=20Report=20Detail=20-=20Part=20Week=2Epdf?=
```

What I want to see is a filename like this:

```
   180 Score Report Detail Part Week.pdf
```

If I log into gmail I can download the file as usual and the file name is as I expect it.  Something is wrong and I do not know why I see this format or how to change it.  I can see the space ASCII 20 in there, but not sure how to convert it all to "normal"?

UPDATE:
Looks like this is.  Not sure if there is a way to extract the file name easily.

```
 print (part.as_string))

 Content-Type: application/pdf
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
 Content-Disposition: Attachment;
 Filename=
 =?utf-8?Q?180=20Score=20Report=20Detail=20-=20Part=20Week=2Epdf?=
```

The email "Subject" also has this formatting with the =?utf-8?...

Any ideas how to parse that string to get it back to plain ASCII text format?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like my question is similar to one asked a year ago.  Not sure I know the answer yet though!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516918/wrong-encoding-of-email-attachment

Comment: see: [`email.header.decode_header()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header)

Comment: `str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header('...header...')))` should work regardless wheather input is encoded or not.